# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de un BSON que me llega a través de un POST en Python?

Tags: python, post, flask, webapi

¿Cómo puedo extraer los datos de un BSON que me llega a través de un POST a mi aplicación escrita en python?

Estoy utilizando flask, y al trabajar con ficheros JSON es tan sencillo como utilizar el modulo request, en plan:

```
request.json.get(nombredelcampo)
```

Ahora bien, ahora quiero empezar a trabajar con archivos grandes, y aunque JSON permite a través de Base64 enviar archivos, quiero utilizar BSON para no aumentar demasiado el tamaño de los POST...

Realizar el envío con curl no hay problema. ¿De qué manera puedo leer lo que me llega por el POST en el servidor? He buscado documentación y apenas he encontrado nada sobre esto, sería genial si me pudierais ayudar.

¡Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Has revisado este proyecto: https://github.com/jar-o/flask-bson/?

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho, es justo lo que buscaba. Un saludo.